# SkyDrive configuration on SharePoint 2013

Tags: configuration

How can I configure SkyDrive on SharePoint 2013?

When I click on skyDrive nothing comes up.

Comment: SkyDrive comes with your live login id, this would all be in your office 2013, sharepoint 2013 will pick this up.

Comment: I don't have office 2013 and a live ID. Where can I create that?

Comment: Well you can't have a skydrive pro account without a 365 or office2013, so you will need a skydrive account. https://skydrive.live.com/

Comment: I created an account, but when I ll go to the sharePoint site on the sharepoint server, still not getting to the skyDrive tab.

Comment: 'OneDrive' ;) edit tba

Answer (score 1):

Skydrive in SharePoint 2013 coms with correct configured User Profile Application Service and MySites. When your MySites are setup, the skydrive tab will lead you to your personal storage within SharePoint.

There is a bad naming confusion with Skydrive, since Microsoft also have personal storage attached to every live-ID account, which can be accessed at http://skydrive.com. There is no relation with Skydrive in SharePoint and your live-ID Skydrive.